# Why does this JavaScript/jQuery functionality work - undeclared variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I try to declare `s` as a variable it errors out. It is acting like `s` isn't a variable and really doesn't like any changes to the syntax at all. 
I've actually written a decision tree webpage that relies on this concept a lot and I'm not sure why it works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Class Tests</title>

 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" charset="UTF-8"/>
    <script src=" jQuery3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src=" jQuery_UI.js"></script>
</head>

    <script>

        function selection(select){
            s = select;                  
        }

         $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function(){

           alert("boop " + s);

            });
        });

    </script>
    <body>
         <button onclick=selection('Genius')>Genius</button>
        <button onclick=selection('System')>Systems</button>
        <button onclick=selection('Personal')>Personal</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you declare a variable without `var` (or `const` or `let`), you're creating a "global variable". After running the `selection` function, in your console, try typing `window.s`; you'll find it's likely defined. If you were to put `var s;` as the first line of your `script`, it would also work.

Comment: Just FYI on this, since I noticed it after the formatting edit - script tags should be placed inside the `<head>` or `<body>` tags, not between (https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1). LPT - If you put the script at the end of the body (after the rest of the body HTML), you don't need to use `$(document).ready()`, since the HTML will be parsed before the script is run.

Comment: Thank you, thank you and... thank you. Let me ask you this... how can i best change this to get rid of this big dirty global variable?

Comment: Figured out a workaround.  thank you again for your help                                                    $(document).ready(function(){
   $("button").click(function(){
    
   var clickButtonCl = this.className;  // "this" is the element clicked
      
    if(clickButtonCl == "Genius"){
     
     $("body").css("background-color", "pink");
    }else if(clickButtonCl == "System"){
     $("body").css("background-color", "orange");
     
    }else if(clickButtonCl == "Personal"){
     $("body").css("background-color", "");
     
    }

Answer (score 0):

> A variable is undeclared when it does not use the var keyword. It gets created on the global object (that is, the window), thus it operates in a different space as the declared variables.

[Find out more on this link](https://lucybain.com/blog/2014/null-undefined-undeclared/)

Answer (score 0):

Setting your `s` like this:

```
function selection(select){
    s = select; 
}
```

is similar (for *variable scope*) to:

```
var s;

function selection(select) {
    s = select; 
}
```

So `s` exists as a property of `window`, and available both inside of `selection` function and for `alert("boop " + s);`, because `window` is a global object.  But if you declare and assign a value to variable with `var` inside a function:

```
function selection(select) {
    var s = select; 
}
```

`s` will have only a *scope* of function `selection`, and retrieving it here:

```
alert("boop " + s);
```

causes an error, because it doesn't exist here.

Answer (score 0):

Variables that are assigned without `var` keyword are called undeclared. These are created in the global scope. So your `s` variable is available in the click handler.

Now this only happens in non-strict mode, so if you put `'use strict'` directive inside or above the selection function you'll get an error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Class Tests</title>

 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" charset="UTF-8"/>
    <script src=" jQuery3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src=" jQuery_UI.js"></script>
</head>

    <script>

        'use strict'

        function selection(select){
            s = select;                  
        }

         $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function(){

           alert("boop " + s);

            });
        });

    </script>
    <body>
         <button onclick=selection('Genius')>Genius</button>
        <button onclick=selection('System')>Systems</button>
        <button onclick=selection('Personal')>Personal</button>
    </body>
</html>
```